# my animation is on other background then my button

Tags: html, css

The bubbles are moving from down to up thats what i wanted but they cant get through some weird rectangle thats creating around my button. its like there are two backgrounds but i cant see where is the second one. when i make height of body 100% background just follows button and then animation starts like on new page under it.

```css
body {
  background-image: url('imagep.jpg')
}

box-sizing:border-box;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;

}
html,
body {
  height: %;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  position: relative;
  margin: 32px;
}

/* button 1*/
.btn-1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(143, 64, 248, 0.5), 0 0 0 0 rgba(39, 200, 255, 0.5);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease, box-shadow 0.3s ease;
}
.btn-1::after {
  content: '';
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: -100px;
  background-color: #ff3cac;
  background-image: linear-gradient(225deg, #27d86c 0%, #26caf8 50%, #c625d0 100%);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}
.btn-1:hover {
  transform: translate(0, -6px);
  box-shadow: 10px -10px 25px 0 rgba(143, 64, 248, 0.5), -10px 10px 25px 0 rgba(39, 200, 255, 0.5);
}
.btn-1:hover::after {
  transform: rotate(150deg);
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.anima {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.bubbles {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}
.bubbles span {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: #4fc3dc;
  margin: 0 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #4fc3dc44, 0 0 50px #4fc3dc, 0 0 100px #4fc3dc;
  animation: animate 15s linear infinite;
  animation-duration: calc(125s / var(--i));
}
.bubbles span:nth-child(even) {
  background: #ff2d75;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #ff2d7544, 0 0 50px #ff2d75, 0 0 100px #ff2d75;
}
@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(100vh) scale(0);
  }
  
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-10vh) scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="buttons"><a href="content.html" class="btn btn-1">Click Me</a></div>
</div>
<div class='anima'>
  <div class='bubbles'>
    <span style='--i:11;'></span>
    <span style='--i:12;'></span>
    <span style='--i:24;'></span>
    <span style='--i:10;'></span>
    <span style='--i:14;'></span>
    <span style='--i:23;'></span>
    <span style='--i:18;'></span>
    <span style='--i:16;'></span>
    <span style='--i:19;'></span>
    <span style='--i:20;'></span>
    <span style='--i:22;'></span>
    <span style='--i:25;'></span>
    <span style='--i:18;'></span>
    <span style='--i:21;'></span>
    <span style='--i:15;'></span>
    <span style='--i:13;'></span>
    <span style='--i:26;'></span>
    <span style='--i:17;'></span>
    <span style='--i:13;'></span>
    <span style='--i:28;'></span>
    <span style='--i:11;'></span>
    <span style='--i:12;'></span>
    <span style='--i:24;'></span>
    <span style='--i:10;'></span>
    <span style='--i:14;'></span>
    <span style='--i:23;'></span>
    <span style='--i:18;'></span>
    <span style='--i:16;'></span>
    <span style='--i:19;'></span>
    <span style='--i:20;'></span>
    <span style='--i:22;'></span>
    <span style='--i:25;'></span>
    <span style='--i:18;'></span>
    <span style='--i:21;'></span>
    <span style='--i:15;'></span>
    <span style='--i:13;'></span>
    <span style='--i:26;'></span>
    <span style='--i:17;'></span>
    <span style='--i:13;'></span>
    <span style='--i:28;'></span>
  </div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please make it a [mcve]

Comment: I can’t see where the animation is created.

Comment: It's not clear what you want - to have the bubbles go around the button?

Comment: Yes i want to bubbles go around it